# Angular 5 ActivatedRoute and FlatMap

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make http request depending on the query params without nested .subscribes.

```
this.activeRoute.queryParamMap
.map((params: ParamMap) => params.get('query'))
.flatMap(query => this.httpService.getWeatherForecast(query))
.subscribe( .......)
```

However, I'm receiving following error

`this.activeRoute.queryParamMap.map is not a function`

Comment: Have you added `import rxjs/add/operator/map` to the file?

Comment: Actually, it wasn't the map but the mergeMap. Since the flatMap is an alias of mergeMap